# Is there a scale indicator bar for the Maps app on iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-maps, maps

I'm using Google Maps in the Maps app on my iPad but I cannot find a scale bar.
Where is the scale bar for Google Maps in the native Maps app on an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no scale bar in Maps for iPad. I think it is not official (yet) because even on Android it can only be enabled from the "Labs" settings. So, it is not part of the official Google Maps images.

Answer (score 0):

There is no scale bar in the Maps app, but you can use the app Mapscale, which gives you exactly what you desire.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you provide some more info? Please provide a link to the app and tell us what it does and why you're recommending it. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.